# Can't Change expandMain Fedora Partition with GParted

Tags: fedora, gparted

I am trying to expand my main Fedora partition and have live booted but I still cant move sda3 over so I can expand into the allocated space.

[Picture of GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V71rE.png)

Comment: You need to use lvm tools.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Can you elaborate?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because I don't use lvm but I know you need special tools for that instead of GParted. A Google search should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows the /dev/sda3 partition as containing a **L**ogical **V**olume **M**anager version **2** **P**hysical **V**olume, or LVM2 PV.  All of the space within the LVM2 PV appears to be allocated to LVM2 **L**ogical **V**olume(s).  Usually each LVM2 LV will contain a file system such as ext4.  LVM2 is a special type of formatting that permits file systems to span across multiple physical disk drives.

The lock icon beside /dev/sda3 indicates that the partition is active or in-use.  In order to move or resize /dev/sda3 it must first be deactivated by selecting the partition and using the menu option **Partition -> Deactivate**.  Then the partition and the enclosed LVM2 PV can be moved or resized.

Note that if you increase the size of the LVM2 PV then to use the new space inside you need to use commands like `lvmresize` to grow  the LVM2 LVs.  I think when the LVM2 LV is grown then you can grow the file system within using a command like `resize2fs` for ext2/3/4 file systems.

I highly recommend that you make a backup of your data and also read up on LVM2 before changing the disk organization.

Personally I find the added flexibility of LVM2 unnecessarily complex, so I install GNU/Linux directly into partitions with file systems like ext4.